# How to get all the groups for a contact

Tags: api

Starting from a contact ID, i need to find all the groups to which the contact belongs.

I know that i can use api `GroupContact` but it doesn't work for smart groups (in CiviCRM 4.5)

Is there any api calls that will retrieve all groups at once ?
Otherwise, what would be the best way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the Groups, you can use the `GroupContact` API

```
$result = civicrm_api3('GroupContact', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'contact_id' => <contact_id>,
));
```

To get all the smart groups to which the contact belongs, you can use this BAO function defined in GroupContactCache.php

```
$smartGroup = CRM_Contact_BAO_GroupContactCache::contactGroup($contactId);
```

returned `$smartGroup` will be the list of smart_groups for the `contactId` passed

Comment: Thanks @Jitendra. Does that mean that you have tested that the GroupContact API does not return Smart Groups?

Comment: yes, `civicrm_group_contact` does not have an entry for smart groups with status `Added` as it does other normal groups.

Comment: Thanks Jitendra Purohit. It's a shame there is no function to get all at once.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the api call "civicrm_api3_group_contact_get($params)" where you are passing contact_id, I think it will return all groups, whether 'Smart' or not - did you try it?  That call just passes contact_id and if status is 'added' it should return the group

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no, it doesn't. civicrm_api3_group_contact_get is linked to the civicrm table civicrm_group_contact which is only for member statically added to group.

Answer (score 0):

I am almost sure that the API GroupContact also returns Smart Group membership, my recommendation would be to test.